# What is the best approach to develope a large connected/disconnected application

Tags: php, linux

We need to write an application that has two parts: One side of the users will be using it running in a disconnected environment (connecting every few hours to the internet), the other side will be fully connected monitoring the disconnected clients. The requirement exists that it must run on a browser.

We are proficient in PHP so I think we are going this route, my question is..  how would you lay this out on a high level?

Use web services for everything? DB replication with each client having their own DB? Use of PHP frameworks?

Thank you.

Comment: Are the disconnected clients mobile devices? e.g. iPhone, BlackBerry's, iPad, Android etc. or are they Laptops/Desktops? - It doesn't really matter, but there's some options that are better/worse depending on the remote device.

Comment: Are you running the website/application in your network, or is it stored on a remotely? If you do it localy in your network i think to setup a local database or create a cache system. so the time your connected to the database it merge/syncronize the data you got in your local database or cache system(Its just a thought).

Comment: Its not clear, are you planning for a web application that can be accessed locally, or a hosted solution.

Comment: So the main question is whether to use an RDBMS or something else? This something else might be a [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) framework (perhaps MongoDB which supports PHP?).

Comment: The disconnected clients are trailers that will be off-road for several hours at a time. The idea is that each trailer will have a server to serve the application, then each client in the other side of the trailer can access it.. Then, when the trailer comes to a dock they can connect to the internet and synch up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want to hassle with installing webservers (with PHP) on each clients' computer, i would definately NOT use PHP for the disconnected clients (disregarding the fact that you could create a nice installer for the whole package).

Since you MUST install a webserver to allow use of a disconnected PHP 'client-side' application, this also defeats the requirement of that it must run in a browser (if that is the sole requirement).

I would look at something else (like Java), compile it and use offline storage like files or even a lite db like sqllite and then just sync it every now and then.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run offline with a browser that means you need to run some sort of webserver on the local machine with php.

Running multiple offline data storage instances that needs to sync with a central database sounds like CouchDB.

What PHP Framework you use... that's dependend on your preferences. Only pre-requisite is a DB Abstraction Layer for CouchDB (oryou write one yourself)

Comment: We tend not to use any framework... I am trying to push for ZendFramework since I like the idea of having a basic structure for all we do.

Comment: For your use case I would recommend to NOT use a RDBMS.
The problem is the offline work and sync with the master RDBMS.
CouchDB is especially written for this use case.
I would give it a look.